# Swift - Core data

Tags: swift, appdelegate

I need help with `swift - core data`

```
import CoreData
import UIKit

class CoreDataHelper: NSObject{

    let store: CoreDataStore!

    class var sharedInstance:CoreDataHelper {
        return cdh
    }

    init(){
        super.init()

        // all CoreDataHelper share one CoreDataStore defined in AppDelegate
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        self.store =  CoreDataStore.sharedInstance;

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "contextDidSaveContext:", name: NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, object: nil)
    }
 }
```

Application force closes at

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
```

Comment: Can you share error that that you receive in xCode?

Comment: BTW: in Swift you must invoke super.init() in the end of the init method.

Comment: try this:

    `if let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate {
        self.store = CoreDataStore.sharedInstance
        ...
    }
    else {
        println( "oops, appDelegate is nil" )
    }`

and tell us what's going on.

Comment: Thank you very much It works                                                 fabrice truillot de chambrier